# MongoDB - How to use a field value in a $slice projection?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Given a simple document such as:

```
{
    myArray : [12, 10, 40, -1, -1, ..., -1],  //'-1' is a int placeholder
    latestUpdatedIndex : 2
}
```

I know how many values I will put in `myArray` so I preallocate space with the `-1` values to make updates more efficient. I keep track of the latest value I updated in `latestUpdatedIndex`

Can I use the value of `latestUpdatedIndex` in a `$slice` projection like the one below?

```
coll.find({}, {'myArray':{'$slice':[0, <value of latestUpdatedIndex>]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using a normal query but you can do it using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice) (in MongoDB 3.2):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { mySlicedArray: { $slice: [ "$myArray", "$latestUpdatedIndex" ] } } }
])
```